# Class 'AuthGaurd' incorrectly implements interface CanActivate

Tags: angular, interface, observable, angular-guards

I am beginner and learning Angular From tutorials as i follow those tutorials and when i implement interface **`CanAcivate`** as he did in tutorial its show error

**Class 'AuthGaurd' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.
  Property 'canActivate' is missing in type 'AuthGaurd' but required in type 'CanActivate'.ts(2420)**

Here is implementation of Canactivate

```
export class AuthGaurd implements CanActivate
{
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  CanActivate(){
    return this.auth.user$.map(user => {
      if (user) return true;
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    });
  }
}`
```

And here is Imports

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
    import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router/src/utils/preactivation';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

I change Import from `import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router/src/utils/preactivation';` to `import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router; But not work`

Also I add following in canActivate as i watch one answer on StackOverflow but it also not work for me

```
 CanActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
 state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean>
```

Comment: The method should be canActivate(). i.e in camelCase. Please refer to https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the camel case of the `canActivate` function and use the necessary parameters to implement the function.

Answer (score 4):

your method should be **canActivate()** and it should return `Observable<boolean> | boolean`:

```
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
      this.auth.user$.map(user => {
          if (user) return true;
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    });
    }
```

Comment: Will it work fine without this "route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean "

Comment: it's best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a boolean from the `canActivate` method. There's a spelling mistake in your method. it should be `canActivate` instead of `CanActivate`. `CanActivate` is a interface name where as `canActivate` is the method name

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
     RouterStateSnapshot, Router, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';

export class AuthGaurd implements CanActivate
{
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){

    this.auth.user$.map(user => {
      if (user) return true ;
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    });


  }
}
```